# What is wrong with this log4.net configuration?

Tags: wpf, log4net, log4net-configuration

It sure looks like it should work.  It throws no errors, steps through every line of code, but produces no log file.  What is wrong here?  It should produce a log file in the directory of the appender name, but no log file ever generates.

log4net.xml file:

```
<configuration>
  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name ="task_appender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingAppender">
      <file value="C:\Users\ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Workout Project\GPWorkouts\blablabla.txt"></file>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBacks value="2"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="5000KB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"></conversionPattern>
      </layout>   
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="Task">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="task_appender"/>
    </logger>

  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

application file:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        static protected ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("Task");

        static void log4net_demo() 
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("log4net.xml");
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(fi);
            log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["host"] = Environment.MachineName;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            log4net_demo();
            log.Info("This is the information log level");
            log.Debug("This is the debugging log level");
            log.Error("This is the error log level");
            log.Fatal("This is the fatal log level");


        }
```

Comment: [Enable internal debugging](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug) and see if it tells you something useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some typo in your log4net config, the correct appender type name is `log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender`

In your xml, it was given as `log4net.Appender.RollingAppender`

Here is the corrected xml

```
<configuration>
  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name ="task_appender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Users\ryan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Workout Project\GPWorkouts\blablabla.txt"></file>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBacks value="2"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="5000KB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"></conversionPattern>
      </layout>   
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="Task">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="task_appender"/>
    </logger>

  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Nice find.  I fixed the file name, re-ran the application but it is still not generating a log file.

Comment: make sure log4net.xml exists in the binary folder. Turn on log4net debugging switch to get additional details. That is much helpful.

Comment: I figured it out.  it was the line of code in the AssemblyInfo.cs file that tells the application to look at the log4net.config file.  [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]

Comment: Glad, figured it out.